# Get the selected tabs in Visual studio for Visual studio extension (VSIX)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

I would like to get the array of the selected tab objects programmatically as the selection below:

[image]

I could only find the way to get the array of selected files in the Solution Explorer:

[image]

But it is not that array that I need.

Does anyone know how to get the array of the selected tabs in C#?

Comment: Check these two [VsBrushes.ToolWindowTabTextKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsbrushes.toolwindowtabtextkey?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) Property and [VsBrushes.ToolWindowTabSelectedTabKey](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.vsbrushes.toolwindowtabselectedtabkey?view=visualstudiosdk-2017) Property. Hope it could help you.

Comment: Hi Jason, any update for this issue? Please check if **Matze**'s answer helps to resolve this issue. Just a reminder :)

Comment: @Jason, if you've been able to solve the problem, could you please share the code as an answer. This would be quite helpful for the others like me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tabs in Visual Studio represent open documents; so you may want to iterate over the document collection instead, that is accessible via the `Documents` property of the `DTE` instance. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte._dte.documents?view=visualstudiosdk-2017#EnvDTE__DTE_Documents for further information.

Each `Document` returned by `Documents` collection allows us to find related windows (those are usually document-windows, but not tool-windows); see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/envdte.document.windows?view=visualstudiosdk-2017 for further information about objects returned by the `Windows` property.

The `Window` class has properties that might be suitable, for whatever you wanna do with it; for instance ask for its caption, visibility, type, handle, etc.., but I am not sure whether it is possible to determine or derive the information whether the document window´s tab (or document itself) is selected, or not.

As an alternative, you can also use the `RunningDocumentTable` service to iterate open documents; see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.runningdocumenttable?view=visualstudiosdk-2017

Comment: I will accept your answer, because I found that Microsoft doesn't provide this kind of functionality for the tabs and your answer lead me to a correct direction to find the answer. Thanks